# Compute a definite integral that involves exponentials and trigonometric functions.

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, power-series, utility

Let $ r > 0 $ and let $\vec{\gamma} = (\gamma_i)_{i=1}^2 $ such that $\gamma_{1} > 0 $, $\gamma_2 > 0 $ and such that $ \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 < 1$. We consider the following integral:

\begin{equation}
J(r,\vec{\gamma}) := \int\limits_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\left( e^{r \cos(\phi)}-1,  e^{r \sin(\phi)}-1 \right)}{1+\gamma_1\cdot (e^{r \cos(\phi)}-1) + \gamma_2 \cdot (e^{r \sin(\phi)}-1) } d\phi
\end{equation}

This integral appears in the context of logarithmic utility portfolio optimization as in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHz9t.png).

We have found a series expansion of this integral for small values of $r$. It reads:

\begin{equation}
J(r,\vec{\gamma}) = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty r^{2 m} \cdot \sum\limits_{n=0}^{2 m} (-1)^n \binom{n}{p}  \gamma_1^{n-p} \gamma_2^p \cdot \left(C^{(1,m)}_{n-p,p}, C^{(2,m)}_{n-p,p} \right) \quad (i)
\end{equation}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
C^{(1,m)}_{n-p,p} &:=& \sum\limits_{l_1=0}^{n-p+1} \sum\limits_{l_2=0}^p \binom{n-p+1}{l_1} \binom{p+0}{l_2} (-1)^{n+1-l_1-l2} \cdot \frac{(l_1^2+l_2^2)^m}{(m!)^2 \cdot 2^{2 m}} \\
C^{(2,m)}_{n-p,p} &:=& \sum\limits_{l_1=0}^{n-p+1} \sum\limits_{l_2=0}^p \binom{n-p+0}{l_1} \binom{p+1}{l_2} (-1)^{n+1-l_1-l2} \cdot \frac{(l_1^2+l_2^2)^m}{(m!)^2 \cdot 2^{2 m}}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, there is an obvious question whether the series $(i)$ converge. I have tested it numerically . Below I show the number of terms that need to be taken into account in order to achieve an accuracy of nine decimal digits. In here I used $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2) = (0.1,0.2)$ (top-left), $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2) = (0.25,0.35)$ (top-right), $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2) = (0.333,0.4333)$ (bottom-left) and $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2) = (0.6,0.3)$ (bottom-right). We have:

[image]

As we can see the convergence rate slows down as the $\gamma_1+\gamma_2$ approaches unity from below and as $r$ increases yet even in the worst case scenario, i.e. $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2) = (0.6,0.3)$ and $r=1.4$ we do not need more than twenty terms in order to achieve the required precision.

---

Now, the question that I wanted to ask is how would you be computing this integral for big values of $r$ ? Is there a similar series expansion that one can come up with ?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHz9t.png) Paragraph (4), page 38 in: T Goll, J Kallsen, Optimal portfolios for logarithmic utility, Stochastic Processes and their Applications 89 (2000), 31-48

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a partial answer to this question only.

First of all let us give the large $r$ limit of the integrand. We define:
\begin{equation}
f(r,\phi):= \frac{\left( e^{r \cos(\phi)}-1,  e^{r \sin(\phi)}-1 \right)}{1+\gamma_1\cdot (e^{r \cos(\phi)}-1) + \gamma_2 \cdot (e^{r \sin(\phi)}-1) } d\phi \quad (i)
\end{equation}
and we have:

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} f(r,\phi) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
\frac{1}{\gamma_1} \cdot 1_{-\pi/2 < \phi < \pi/4} - \frac{1}{1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2} \cdot 1_{\pi < \phi < 3/2 \pi} \\
\frac{1}{\gamma_2} \cdot 1_{+\pi/4 < \phi < \pi} - \frac{1}{1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2} \cdot 1_{\pi < \phi < 3/2 \pi}
\end{array}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Below we can see a plot of the integrand $(i)$ for fixed $r = 100$ and $\gamma_1,\gamma_2 = 0.6,0.3 $. We conclude that the large $r$ limit is achieved very fast.

[image]

Therefore we conclude that:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty } J(r,\vec{\gamma}) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
\frac{1}{\gamma_1}  \cdot \frac{3}{4} \pi - \frac{1}{1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \\
\frac{1}{\gamma_2}  \cdot \frac{3}{4} \pi - \frac{1}{1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

---

Now let us look at the finite-$r$ corrections.

We define:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda^{\phi_-,\phi_+}_{r} &:=& \int\limits_{\phi_-}^{\phi_+} e^{-r \cdot \sin(\phi)} d\phi \\
&=&
\frac{1}{r} \sum\limits_{m=0} \binom{m-1/2}{m} \frac{1}{r^{2 m}} \cdot 
\gamma(2m+1,x_1,x_+ )
\end{eqnarray}
where $x_- :=  r \sin(\phi_-) \wedge r \sin(\phi_+) $ and $x_- :=  r \sin(\phi_-) \vee r \sin(\phi_+) $ .

---

We  split our integrals accordingly.

\begin{eqnarray}
J_1(r,\vec{\gamma}) &=& 
\underbrace{\int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/4} f_1(r,\phi) d\phi}_{{\mathcal J}_{1,a}} +
\underbrace{\int\limits_{+\pi/4(1+\epsilon)}^{\pi(1-\epsilon} f_1(r,\phi) d\phi}_{{\mathcal J}_{1,b}} +
\underbrace{\int\limits_{\pi(1+\epsilon)}^{3\pi/2(1-\epsilon)} f_1(r,\phi) d\phi}_{{\mathcal J}_{1,c}} \\
J_2(r,\vec{\gamma}) &=& 
\underbrace{\int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/4} f_2(r,\phi) d\phi}_{{\mathcal J}_{2,a}} +
\underbrace{\int\limits_{+\pi/4}^{\pi} f_2(r,\phi) d\phi}_{{\mathcal J}_{2,b}} +
\underbrace{\int\limits_{\pi}^{3\pi/2} f_2(r,\phi) d\phi}_{{\mathcal J}_{2,c}}
\end{eqnarray}

1. Now we analyze the quantity ${\mathcal J}_{1,a}$. Define $(c_1,c_2) := \left((1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2)/\gamma_1, \gamma_2/\gamma_1\right)$ then $\left(\theta_{n,p},\bar{\theta}_{n,p}\right) := \left( \arctan(n/(n-p)), \arctan((n+1)/(n-p)) \right)$ and we have:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal J}_{1,a} &=& \frac{1}{\gamma_1} \cdot
\int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/4} \left(
\frac{1-e^{-r \cos(\phi)}}{1 + c_1 e^{-r \cos(\phi)} + c_2 e^{-r \sqrt{2} \cos(\phi+\pi/4)}}
\right) d\phi \\
&=& \frac{1}{\gamma_1} \cdot 
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum\limits_{p=0}^n \binom{n}{p} c_1^p \cdot c_2^{n-p} 
\left(
%\int\limits_{\theta_{n,p} - \pi/4}^{\theta_{n,p} +\pi/2} 
%e^{-r \sqrt{n^2+(n-p)^2} \cdot \sin(\phi) } d\phi
\lambda^{\theta_{n,p} - \pi/4,\theta_{n,p} +\pi/2}_{r \sqrt{n^2+(n-p)^2}}
-
%\int\limits_{\bar{\theta}_{n,p} - \pi/4}^{\bar{\theta}_{n,p} +\pi/2} 
%e^{-r \sqrt{(n+1)^2+(n-p)^2} \cdot \sin(\phi) } d\phi
\lambda^{\bar{\theta}_{n,p} - \pi/4,\bar{\theta}_{n,p} +\pi/2}_{r \sqrt{(n+1)^2+(n-p)^2}}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}

2. We analyze the quantity ${\mathcal J}_{2,a}$. Define $(c_1,c_2) := \left((1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2)/\gamma_2, \gamma_2/\gamma_2\right)$ then $\left(\theta_{n,p},\bar{\theta}_{n,p}\right) := \left( \arctan((n+1-p)/(n+1)), \arctan((n+0-p)/(n+1)) \right)$ and then we have:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal J}_{1,b} &=& \frac{1}{\gamma_2} \cdot
\int\limits_{\pi/4(1+\epsilon)}^{\pi(1-\epsilon)} \left(
\frac{
e^{r \sqrt{2} \cos(\phi+\pi/4)}-
e^{-r \sin(\phi)}
}{
1 + c_1 e^{-r \sin(\phi)} + c_2 e^{r \sqrt{2} \cos(\phi+\pi/4)}
}
\right) d\phi \\
&=& \frac{1}{\gamma_2} \cdot 
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum\limits_{p=0}^n \binom{n}{p} c_1^p \cdot c_2^{n-p} 
\left(
\lambda^{\pi/4(1+\epsilon) -\theta_{n,p},\pi(1-\epsilon) -\theta_{n,p}}_{r \sqrt{(n+1)^2+(n+1-p)^2}}
-
\lambda^{\pi/4(1+\epsilon)-\bar{\theta}_{n,p},\pi(1-\epsilon) - \bar{\theta}_{n,p}}_{r \sqrt{(n+1)^2+(n+0-p)^2}}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}

3. Finally we analyze the quantity ${\mathcal J}_{1 c}$. Define $(c_1,c_2) := \left(\gamma_1/(1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2),\gamma_2/(1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2)\right)$ then $\left(\theta_{n,p},\bar{\theta}_{n,p}\right) := \left( \arctan(p/(n-p)), \arctan((p+1)/(n-p)) \right)$ and then we have:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal J}_{1,c} &=& \frac{1}{1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2} \cdot
\int\limits_{\pi(1+\epsilon)}^{3/2\pi(1-\epsilon)} \left(
\frac{
-1+
e^{r \cos(\phi)}
}{
1 + c_1 e^{r \cos(\phi)} + c_2 e^{r \sin(\phi)}
}
\right) d\phi \\
&=& \frac{1}{1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2} \cdot 
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum\limits_{p=0}^n \binom{n}{p} c_1^p \cdot c_2^{n-p} 
\left(
\lambda^{-\pi(1+\epsilon) -\theta_{n,p},-3/2\pi(1-\epsilon) -\theta_{n,p}}_{r \sqrt{(p+0)^2+(n-p)^2}}
-
\lambda^{-\pi(1+\epsilon)-\bar{\theta}_{n,p},-3/2\pi(1-\epsilon) - \bar{\theta}_{n,p}}_{r \sqrt{(p+1)^2+(n-p)^2}}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}